# How to auto-populate field in Django admin based on another fields value

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I want to make a dependent auto-populate field which get populated with custom values when another field is selected by the user. I have searched but was not able to find the correct help.

[My case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM3Zg.png)

I want when the fertiliser name is selected the above field "phosphate" etc. should get populated based on the fertiliser name selected.

Comment: If you don't want to write javascript code then you can use django-autocomplete-light package. For more info- https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.3/tutorial.html?highlight=re#filtering-results-based-on-the-value-of-other-fields-in-the-form

Comment: Thank you, but what i want is that, the fields should get populated with values associated with the fertiliser name, for ex., lets say you select a cars model, all the corresponding features like engine specs and all should automatically get populated with that.

Comment: please add code of model and view for question clarity